# I want to know which determines the output like not in this case applies to first condition only or both

Tags: python, operators, operator-precedence

```py
x=(not (5==5) and (10<12))
print(x)
```

when executing. not negates the first expression or both?

In my opinion "not" should be executed with (5==5) only but my colleague says it will affect the whole expression in the bracket like (5==5) and (10<12).

Comment: Python cares nothing for your opinions, only for what code you have written. What other experiments did you try and what can you conclude from them?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the approach I use. Instead of and we can place **or** operation to verify the answer. The result shows **True**
. As the result is true so we can say that **not (5==5)** applies first. If the **not** operation runs with **((5==5) or (10<12))** then final result should be False. Hope it will help to understand.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I did it with OR also and it worked the same way as you are telling.

Comment: I am sorry but I couldn't understand your second statement.
>>> not 0 and 2
2
Python calculated not 0 and since it is True, continued through the and.

Why is this true when you say **not 0**. shouldn't it be false?

Answer (score 0):

It all comes down to [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). Looking at the table, `not` is higher than `and` so it goes first. So you are right, the `not` goes with the `(5==5)`.

You can test with a simpler example.

```
>>> not 1 and 2
False
```

Python calculated `not 1` and since it's `False`, it short-circuited the `and` operation.

```
>>> not 0 and 2
2
```

Python calculated `not 0` and since it is True, continued through the `and`.

```
>>> not (0 and 2)
True
```

Your colleague's prediction was wrong.

```
>>> (not 0) and 2
2
```

Your prediction worked!

Comment: I am sorry but I couldn't understand your second statement.

Comment: In `not 0 and 2`, python first evaluated the `not 0`, which is `True`. Now the expression is `True and 2`. Since `and` tests that both sides are `True`, it still needs to evaluate the right hand side. `2` is `True` making the expression `True and True`. `and` and `or` are a bit strange - they return the last evaluated value, not simply `True` or `False`. `2` was the last thing evaluated, so that's what you get.

Comment: If you have an expression like `not x and y` - its kinda bizarre. You either get `False` or whatever the value of `y` is.